# Eloquent accessing array inside object

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a get formule that returns some nested relationships in an array. I was wondering how to access them in a where statement.

The initial get

```
$taken = UserWork::with('work.place')
            ->with('user')
            ->with('work.timeslot')
            ->get();
```

I tried something like this

```
$taak = $taken->where('work.timeslot[0].start_hour',"17:00:00")->first();
```

json result from $taken

[image: json result from $taken]

Comment: do u want to get the `userworks` records and its `timeslot` which start_hour is `17:00:00`.Or u can post the example that u expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `with` will endup with two queries. if you want to bring the user with timeslot `null` then there no need to add `whereHas`

```
    $callback = function($query) {
        $query->where('start_hour',"17:00:00");
    };

    $taken = UserWork::whereHas('work.timeslot', $callback)
        ->with(
            ['work.place', 'user', 'work.timeslot' => $callback]
        )->get();
```